# Python - Calculating the required number of natural numbers

Tags: python

I have to calculate, at least how many of the first consecutive natural numbers (that is, positive integers, for example, 1, 2, 3, ...), we must multiply that the product is at least entered (therefore, the product of numbers must be greater than or equal to the entered number). Make a calculation using the loop. The program should list the answer in the statement. If you enter 33, the answer is: "To get at least 33, we need to multiply the first 5 natural numbers."

Comment: do you have any code you wrote to show us? This ain't too tough; you can do it!

Comment: You should post an attempt, even it it didn't get far. See also https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
x = int(input("Enter a Number"))
count = 1
j = 1
for i in range(1,x):
    count =  count * i
    if count >= x: # Count till your product is greater than or equal to entered number
       j = i
       break # Break here to avoid anymore loop
print ("To get at least {}, we need to multiply the first {} natural numbers.".format(x,j))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this was very helpful as I am new to programming and it is an obligatory subject.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
number_calc = 33

def calculate(number):
  last_number = 1
  prod = 1
  if number == 1:
      pass
  else:
    while prod <= number :
      last_number = last_number + 1
      prod = prod*last_number
  return last_number

answer = calculate(number_calc)
print("To get at least {}, we need to multiply the first {} natural numbers.".format(number_calc,answer))
```

But you should listen to the comments and try it by yourself, it's a very basic code sample.

Comment: `if number == 1: pass  else:` would be better written as `if number >1:`, but is unnecessary anyway, just start directly with the loop, changing the condition to `while prod < number`.

Comment: that's true, i've just write it one shot while talking with a friend haha, thank you for the precision;